# How to extract only ID's from object after groupingBy in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Element {

    private Long id;

    private String groupType;

}
```

> I have List of Elements.  List with different groupType like
>   'group1', 'group2' {1,group1},{2,group1},{3,group2}{4,group2}
>
> I want to create map with two different list for each group but with
>   the ids(Map>) not with the Element object
>   Map>
>
> below code is working fine for Map> i.e

```
Map<String, List<Element>> elementByGroup = new HashMap<>();
        elementByGroup = element.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getGroupType));
```

> How can i collect result in the form of Map< String, List < Long > >. I know
>   by iterating Map and then iterating list we can get List of id's
>   without java 8. However I want to do the same by manipulating with
>   above code after groupingby function.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [Collectors.mapping()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). It would look like this

```
Map<String, List<Long>> idsByGroupType = 
  elements.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getGroupType,
      Collectors.mapping(Element::getId, Collectors.toList())));
```